# Retrieve related objects with Doctrine and Symfony

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-query

I searched for a long time, but I don't manage to retrieve two related object in one query. I am using [Doctrine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_%28PHP%29) and [Symfony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) (uses Doctrine by default).

Here is a part of my schema.yml:

```
Member:
  columns:
    ...some fields...

Report:
  columns:
    member:       { type: integer, notnull: true }
    ...some fields...
  relations:
    Member:  { onDelete: CASCADE, local: member, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Members }
```

And this my "basic" request which works to retrieve only the report object:

```
public function getReports($place,$max = 5) {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Report sr')
            ->where('sr.place = ?',$place)
            ->limit($max)
            ->orderBy('sr.date DESC');
    return $q->execute();
}
```

A report has been committed by a member in a place. I need to retrieve the member object to display it with his fields but I really don't know how to do that.

If you have a clue or method to do that, I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->from('Report sr')
->innerJoin('sr.Members m');
```

That's it, quite simple :)

Comment: I already tried something like that with some leftJoin but symfony throws exceptions like this :

500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Table_Exception
Unknown relation alias Members

Comment: For information, I cleared cache and the relation is as pasted in the question

Comment: Hmmm my mistake, it should be Member, not Members.

Comment: No it's not Members. You relation is called Member. The foreignAlias part is used for reverse-relations. http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#relationships:foreign-key-associations:one-to-many-and-many-to-one